# Sending feedback directly from the application

Tags: android, ios, feed, testflight

Could you tell me how to configure sending feedback directly to developers through the application? Using TestFlight as an example, when can I send feedback via a screenshot taken in the beta version of the application? Also, besides iOS, I would like to try adding this feature on Android as well.

Comment: You will need to use a 3rd party service for this. The service will have a framework/SDK that you add to your app